# Why I'm getting this error? The bot is supposed to assign the role with ID=899279907216031744 , I'm getting error when I'm giving this type of Inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm getting this error below when My Message is something like 003-UG-CSE-2023 or 123-PG-CSE-2024

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\pika bot\pika.py", line 52, in on_message
if cont:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cont' referenced before assignment

```
import os
import discord
import discord.ext.commands as commands
import dotenv
import random

dotenv.load_dotenv()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('I am online')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('-----')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="899279907216031744")
    splits = message.content.split("-")

    # it's not in the wanted format
    if len(splits) != 4:
        # return or something else
        cont = False

    # check if first is a number within range <1, 999>
    try:
        if int(splits[0]) <= 0 and int(splits[0]) >= 1000:
            cont = True
    except ValueError:
        cont = False

    # check if second is one of the options
    if splits[1] not in ["UG", "PG", "D"]:
        cont = False

    # check if third is one of the options
    if splits[2] not in ["CSAI","CSE","ECAI","ECE","IT","MAE","EEE","CE","PD","AE","CH","CE","EE","ME","ED","MV","ER","QT","RAS","AI","CS","CP","BE","CHE","CHEM","CG","CC","VLSI","EV","DES"]:
        cont = False

    # check if fourth is a number from range <2022 ...>
    try:
        if int(splits[3]) <= 2022:
            cont = False
    except ValueError:
        cont = False

    # it fits all the criteria
    if cont:    
        await discord.Member.add_roles(member, role)



bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Please lemme know if you found the mistake so I can fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try/except blocks have their own scope for variables. To use variables set inside a try/except block, you need to add an 'else' or 'finally' after except (where else runs only if there is no error and finally runs either way)

Comment: Can you please elaborate by correcting the code? I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

The Error definitely shows, that the problem is laying on "if cont:", I would try to add cont to a global.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global cont #Added cont to global
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="899279907216031744")
    splits = message.content.split("-")
```